# AngularJS ng-repeat track by not selecting initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Still fairly new to Angular, so please bear with me.  I have a radio button list that I generate using ng-repeat.  I am storing off the selected object in a separate variable on the same controller.

The selected object is being set with a different instance of one of the objects in the list.  I thought that since the ID is the same, that using the "track by" expression would select the correct item in the list, but it isn't.
If I select a radio button, it will update the selected variable as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bad pattern?

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="person in people track by person.id">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="person" />
      {{person.name}}
  </label>
</form>
```

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('ngAppDemo', []).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selected = { id: 2, name: "Paul" };
    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, name: "John" }, 
        { id: 2, name: "Paul" }, 
        { id: 3, name: "George" }, 
        { id: 4, name: "Frank" }
    ];
}
```

Here's my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rK029W6qCEtkFbkIHSBb)

**Update:**
I recognize the fact that if I use an object from the same collection that it will work.  However, this isn't the way I am currently set up.  The instance that I am using for "selected" is coming in from a different function and thus did not originate from the given list.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2bN7ImuFx8yBbBjZcHm2?p=preview  – `track by`is used to not to recreate the DOM elements if you get new data from the server

Comment: http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now it's fixed:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LWXe4dFzfdqTOZXmatpQ?p=preview

You just need to make sure selected points to something in the list.  It doesn't compare by value it compares by reference.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.people = [
    { id: 1, name: "John" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "Paul" }, 
    { id: 3, name: "George" }, 
    { id: 4, name: "Frank" }
];
$scope.selected = $scope.people[1];
}
```

**Update**
All you have to do is simply write the matching routine yourself to match on ID whatever that other function that's producing it's own object and find the same object in your $scope.people list.  For example:

```
function findSelectedPerson( selected ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < $scope.people.length; i++ ) {
        if( $scope.people[i].id == selected.id ) return $scope.people[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

That'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  See my update.  I guess I need to figure out a way to navigate around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that is pretty much what I ended up doing...which there was a way to have it do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

hint

```
$scope.selected = { id: 2, name: "Paul" };
$scope.people = [
    { id: 1, name: "John" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "Paul" }, 
    { id: 3, name: "George" }, 
    { id: 4, name: "Frank" }
];

console.log($scope.selected == $scope.people[1]) // false
```

$scope.selected dose not match anything in $scope.people

Comment: thank you for response.  No hint necessary, I understand that these two objects are not equal. :(  I was trying to use the track by value to seek out a match.